# Play carousel inside [inline] prettyPhoto content modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/3423/

I am trying to activate lightSlider inside of prettyPhoto()[inline] content. When modal loads the inline content the script is active outside a delegated event. However, the content is blank; meaning that it's executing the function. Outside of a delegation event it doesn't work.

I tried doing a delegation even such as `$(document).on('load', function {});`. I tried a couple other delegation events such as hiding an invisible anchor to see if it would fire the jQuery, but it did not.

I read prettyPhoto's documentation and it had the option of running custom content inside it. So, I tried,

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
       custom_markup: '<ul class="gal"></ul>',
       changepicturecallback: function(){ slider); }
    });
    function slider(){
    $('.gal').lightSlider({
        gallery: true,
        item: 1,
        loop: true,
        slideMargin: 0,
        thumbItem: 9
    });
    };
```

However, it produced the same result. How can I run lightslider inside of prettyPhoto, is there a delegation I am not trying or possible trying an on load sequence?

This is my current markup:

HTML

```
<a href="#gal" rel="prettyPhoto[inline]">CLICK ME</a>
<ul id="gal">
  <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg">
    <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg" / class="img"> TEST
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg">
    <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg">
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
$(document).on('click', '#gal', function() {
  $('#gal').show();
  $('#gal').lightSlider({
    gallery: true,
    item: 1,
    loop: true,
    slideMargin: 0,
    thumbItem: 9
  });
});
```

Comment: You forgot to separate your jQuery code from HTML or wrap it into `<script></script>`

Comment: Stack had them lumped together when I copied them in. I edited it.